Comedy/Drama movie from US, probably 2010's. Revolves around young couple and a friendly cop who keeps clumsily trashing their garden
For a few days already I try to remember what the name was of this movie I saw. Problem #1, I only saw the first half hour or so, problem #2, I wasn't exactly in the state of mind to remember every detail ... so this request is probably a bit vague. Here's what I can remember:

The tone was somewhere between comedy and romance. Pretty down-to-earth without silliness or cheesines like an Adam Sandler/Renee Zellweger movie. Slight melancholic tone.
I'm 98% sure it's a production from USA. Remaining 2% are on canada.
At the time watching I did not recognize any actor. That doesn't have to say much, but there were no Academy Award regulars present.
I watched it ~around 2012-2014 and was under the impression that it must have been a fairly recent production.
The story revolved around a white couple in their 30's. They lived alone in a free-standing house in the countryside.
Story takes place in our century.
They were visited once or twice by a cop who was a friend of them and who kept ruining their garden with his car.
For some reason either the couple (or was it just one of them?) had to move from the countryside to the city.
Briefly after I watched the movie's beginning, I managed to track it down on IMDB and noticed it had a rather low (i.e. 5.x to 6.x) user score.

Unfortunately that's everything I really remember. Hope the points I gave are enough to ring a bell for someone.
Ruled out candidates:

Sideways
Blue State


Do you remember what city? Was it recognizable?  Do you know what country it was in? When the cop trashed their garden, was it silly slapstick, or were their reactions more based in reality?

Unfortunately, I can't give any more details about locations. It could have been anywhere in the US or Canada. The garden trashing was borderline slapstick. Either the cop passed out while steering the car or it rolled away due to lack of tight handbrake iirc.
